# Constant output value for multi-variate multi-timeseries regression with LSTMs in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm currently working on a regressional problem with multiple time-series of similar machines and multiple features in Keras with the Tensorflow Backend.

The target is to predict a value at each time-step, which gives the remaining lifetime of the machine.

I normalized all values and padded the in- and output in front of all time sequences to make them as long as longest one.
Then I added the masking layer to mask those zeros.

The problem I have is that the Network is giving me constant values for the output variables.

I already played with the hidden neurons, the batch, the activation functions, the epochs but nothing really changes. 
The loss slowly reduces but the output remains the same for all timesteps. 
Oh, and it kind of worked for one time-sequences.

For all zero-padded rows I get some value like `4.88323085e-02` (which is good I guess?) and for all others the output looks like this:

```
[...
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01,
8.72270355e+01,   8.72270355e+01]
```

My data is formed like:

```
[n_machines, n_timesteps, n_features]
```

And the output looks like:

```
[n_machines, n_timesteps, remaining_life]
```

My current model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(1000, return_sequences = True, unit_forget_bias=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=[RMSE])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
```

Using something instead of Neural Nets is sadly not an option so I need to make this work.
Would be happy if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: I would try increasing the `batch_size`.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I already tried a batch size of 10 which didn't help. I only have 100 sequences after all.

Comment: What are statistics of your target. Could you plot histogram of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days testing and playing around I figured out a working configuration. Apparently what I needed was a stateful LSTM. Here's my working solution:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., batch_input_shape=(1, 362, 105)))
model.add(
    LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, unit_forget_bias=True, stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation="linear")))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=[RMSE])

# Train the model
for epoch in range(200):
    print('Epoch %s' % epoch)
    train_loss=[]

    # Train
    for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
        tr_loss, tr_RMSE = model.train_on_batch(x_train[i, :, :].reshape((1, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])), y_train[i, :, :].reshape(((1, y_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[2]))))
        train_loss.append(tr_loss)
        model.reset_states()
print('loss training = {}'.format(np.mean(train_loss)))
```

Comment: Hi. I have a similar problem where I try to predict the remaining time of the process, given multiple processes of varying length. I am using a stateful LSTM but I have some doubts regarding how I am using it. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: To elaborate, I divide each sequence into batches of 30 samples. I train my model for 30 samples and then do `model.reset_states()`. I keep on training it again for the next sequence. Each training epoch has 32 sequences, each divided into a varying number of 30-sized batches. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Also, i am trying to predict just one value. My label is the eta of the process.

Comment: I have asked a question about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811017/training-a-multi-variate-multi-series-regression-problem-with-stateful-lstms-in