# Training a multi-variate multi-series regression problem with stateful LSTMs in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have time series of `P` processes, each of varying length but all having 5 variables (dimensions). I am trying to predict the estimated lifetime of a test process. I am approaching this problem with a stateful `LSTM` in Keras. But I am not sure if my training process is correct.

I divide each sequence into batches of length `30`. So each sequence is of the shape `(s_i, 30, 5)`, where `s_i` is different for each of the `P` sequences (`s_i = len(P_i)//30`). I append all sequences into my training data which has the shape `(N, 30, 5)` where `N = s_1 + s_2 + ... + s_p`.

#### Model:

```
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(1, train_X[0].shape[1], train_X[0].shape[2]), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005), metrics=['mse'])
```

The `model.summary()` looks like

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (1, 30, 32)               4864      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (1, 16)                   3136      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (1, 1)                    17        
=================================================================
```

#### Training loops:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    mean_tr_acc = []
    mean_tr_loss = []
        
    for seq in range(train_X.shape[0]): #24
            
        # train on whole sequence batch by batch
        for batch in range(train_X[seq].shape[0]): #68
            b_loss, b_acc = model.train_on_batch(np.expand_dims(train_X[seq][batch], axis=0), train_Y[seq][batch][-1])    
                
            mean_tr_acc.append(b_acc)
            mean_tr_loss.append(b_loss)
                
        #reset lstm internal states after training of each complete sequence
        model.reset_states()
```

#### Edit:

The problem with the loss graph was I was dividing the values in my custom loss, making them too small. If I remove the division and plot the loss graph logarithmically, it looks alright.

#### New Problem:

Once the training is done, I am trying to predict. I show my model a 30 time-samples of a new process; so the input shape is same as the `batch_input_shape` during training i.e. `(1, 30, 5)`. The prediction I am getting for different batches of the same sequence are all same.

I am almost sure I am doing something wrong in the training process. If anyone could help me out, would be grateful. Thanks.

#### Edit 2:

So the model predicts exactly same results only if it has been trained for more than 20 epochs. Otherwise the prediction values are very close but still a bit different. I guess this is due to some kind of overfitting. Help!!!

The loss for 25 epochs looks like this:
[image: loss_25epochs]

Comment: What is the output of the model ? is it a boolean assessing that the process will continue?

Comment: No, the output is a `float` which is the estimated remaining time of the process.

Comment: Should I rather pad every sequence to the same length and shape my training data as `(num_sequences, len_longest_sequence, 5)`?

Comment: What is your custom_loss() function?

Comment: @mlotz my custom loss was a scaled `mse` loss where I was dividing the values by 100. This was causing the previous problem. Now, with ` mse` that is fixed. But the model keeps on predicting the same output value for different test sample batches.

Comment: it does seem like it's overfitting/underfitting. How many data points do you have in your data? Can you get more? If you plot the y values of your training set what does it look like? you might have to over/under sample. Finally, try a different activation function on your Dense. Unfortunately, it is a bit trial and error but do let us know if any of those worked!

Comment: I know that i do not have enough data yet for an LSTM. My main focus till now has been to make sure the training process is alright. I am working of real data, and data collection is going on and it will take some time to get my hands on new data. Now, finally, it seems like the training process is okay and the problem is just lack of data. I am expecting someone to verify/deny my hypothesis. :)

Comment: Right now, I am looking at putting the longer sequences in training, and testing on small ones to check if I can see a bias. Because the current model always predicts remaining time in the range 25 -35 mins, where as the processes can go up to 120 mins.

Comment: @Anakin ok great! because you do not have that much data it will be hard to verify if this is an issue with the structure of the network or the data itself. I would suggest to try and get more points or simplify the structure so that it doesn't overfit.

Comment: Usually when results are the same it's because your data isn't normalized. I suggest you center your data around 0 with a simple normal transform (ie. (data - mean)/std ). Try transforming it like so before training and testing.

Comment: @Turtalicious yes, thanks. I just figured it out yesterday. My input and label data were normalized but on different scales; so the label data was almost 2 magnitudes higher. I have corrected that and now the model does not predict the same values anymore.

Comment: @Anakin I'm glad you got it. ML can be a terrible maze sometimes. Mark the answer as correct and complete so others with the same problem can find it. Unfortunately nobody reads comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when results are the same it's because your data isn't normalized. I suggest you center your data with mean=0 and std=1 with a simple normal transform (ie. (data - mean)/std ). Try transforming it like so before training and testing. Differences in how data is normalized between training and testing sets can also cause problems, which may be the cause of your discrepancy in train vs test loss. Always use the same normalization technique for all your data.